# LESS CSS Put style to THIS tag

Tags: html, css, less

I can't find a solution. For example I have a style in LESS:

```
.any{

  background: #fff;

  a{

    color: #faa;

  }
}
.any.last{
  background: #aaa;
}
.any.last a{
    color: #fa0;
}
```

I want to collect this styles into one brackets?
In different languages it can be done using "$this". But here is no way.
I want to do something like this:

```
.any{

  background: #fff;

  a{

    color: #faa;

  }

  this.last{
  background: #aaa;
  }
  this.last a{
    color: #fa0;
  }
}
```

Thnk you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a **&**:

```
.any {
  background: #fff;

  a {
    color: #faa;
  }

  &.last {
    background: #aaa;
  }
  &.last a {
    color: #fa0;
  }
}
```